# Synchronizing db calls

Tags: android

I have a database schema where i am loading a bunch of clients from a server with data such as first name, last name and id into my db when the app starts. THis data is then displayed in a list format to the user. I have another tab in my app that switches to a view which shows the client list sorted by id into sections similar to the people app with section headers. The trouble is, the user can switch to the sorted list tab immediately upon startup and that list relies on the db already being populated with client objects. It would be making a query on an empty db if the user switches immediately. Is there any way to block that call until the db is fully loaded with the client data? I know java has synchronized methods, so can i sync on the db query or do anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to add an isReady boolean and to loop it is true (assuming a seperate thread is populating the db). Alternatively you can disable the button until it is ready, which is a better solution.

Comment: The two tabs run in their own fragments. Where exactly would this isReady boolean be set and how to manage the data passing between the fragments

Comment: Fragments can interact through different variables, this may not be the cleanest way (i think disabling the tab until it is ready is the best option)... but if you have a public static boolean in the class which fills the db, anyone can access it. So if the fragement checked that boolean and waited until it is true, it should work